# How to remove triangles when page is turning (using CCTransitionPageTurn)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

for digital ebook using cocos2d, triangles are shown when the page is turning. It's bug?
(cocos2d sdk demo has same symptom)

Answer (score 2):

This is documented, tut tut :)

Look for these lines in your AppDelegate...

```
// Create the EAGLView manually
// 1. pixelFormat can be RGB565 or RGBA8.
// 2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
  pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
  depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES  // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, use 0 if you don't need page transition
];
```

And make sure your depth format is at least `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES`.

Comment: how can I accept your answer? I couldn't find menu. sorry. let me know. and I will :)